# Can't delete npf64.sys from HikVision SADP install location - in use by invisible service?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, services, uninstall

I'm trying to fully uninstall HikVision SADP (an IP camera discovery & initial configuration tool) because it isn't working properly and I want to reinstall it cleanly.

The installation path `C:\Program Files (x86)\SADP\SADP` now contains exactly one file: a copy of `npf64.sys`, which is a kernel-mode driver component of WinPCap from Riverbed Technology. (Most likely SADP used this driver as part of its network search functionality).

The rest of SADP has been uninstalled but I can't delete this file. When I try, Windows first asks me to elevate to Admin, and then complains that the file is open in "another program":

[image: Dialog box prohibiting deletion of npf64.sys]

I've used Sysinternals Process Explorer's handle search tool to try to identify the program which is using the file, but it cannot locate any handles pointing to npf64.sys. I also tried sysinternals' `handle.exe` utility, which also cannot find any references.

```
PS C:\Users\me> C:\sysinternals\handle -a "npf64.sys"

Nthandle v4.11 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2017 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

No matching handles found.
PS C:\Users\me> C:\sysinternals\handle -a "npf"

Nthandle v4.11 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2017 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

No matching handles found.
```

I do see a registry key which references this file:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NPF`

[image: Regedit view of registry key pointing to npf64.sys]

And more similar references under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\NPF`

[image: FirstBoot NPF reference]

Can I simply delete these two registry keys (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NPF` and `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\NPF`) which reference this file and reboot, or is there some other approach I should use to clean them up more safely?

I already ran the SADP uninstaller which claimed to have uninstalled the software, but obviously relics have been left behind.

NPF does not appear in the Windows Services MMC snap-in.

Comment: I would use AutoRuns to disable the key responsible for make the file undeletable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was safe to delete the two registry keys which were loading `nfp64.sys` *after* uninstalling SADP.

The two registry keys I deleted were: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NPF` and `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\FirstBoot\Services\NPF`. I then rebooted the computer to unload the kernel module, and was able to delete the `nfp64.sys` file without further issues.